# Не запускается локальный сервер Winginx

Tags: сервер

Не запускается локальный сервер *Winginx*.Использование `80` порта у скайпа отключено.  Локальный *IP* `127.0.0.1` пингуется.В файерволе разрешающие правила вроде прописаны.При старте сервера никаких ошибок не выдается, но при попытке открыть какой-нибудь локальный сайт - `404` ошибка.В чем может быть проблема и как её решить?

Comment: Что происходит, когда Вы запускаете http://localhost?

Comment: конфиги локальный сайтов в студию